# React testing library getting element

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a simple test as I am learning react testing library. I basically took this off of the website. Here is my test:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {render, screen, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react'
    
    import DateInput from '../dateInput';
    
test('calls onChange event is fired', () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn()
    const {getByLabelText} = render(<DateInput ariaLabel='test-date' onChange={onChange}/>);
    const element = getByLabelText('test-date');
    fireEvent.change(element, {target: {value: '2020-05-24'}});
    expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
```

DateInput is a simple component that allows the user to enter a date value. The component boils down to

```
  <div>
    <input
      class="form-control"
      type="date"
      value=""
    />
  </div>
```

So there is an HTML input that I am assuming has a role of 'input'. The test is failing because `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the role "input"`. I am not sure how to get access to this element?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and productive way to get an element is through `aria-label`. It's both good for accessibility (for example screen readers) and easy to target the element.

You could do something like such

**Component**

```
 <input
    class="form-control"
    type="date"
    value=""
    ariaLabel="Departure Date" //Example
 />
```

**Test**

```
test('calls onChange prop when clicked', () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn()
    const {getByLabelText} = render(<DateInput onChange={onChange}/>);
    const element = getByLabelText("Departure Date");
    fireEvent.change(element, {target: {value: '2020-05-24'}});
    expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

Also side note, [try to refrain from using `getByRole` as there is a huge perfordifference using that versus other queries.](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/820)

Comment: I am still getting and error - TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find a label with the text of: test-date. I notice that you don't use 'screen'. Is there a reason? Also aside from the performance hit is there some reason why getByRole in this case would not work? Thank you.

Comment: Also I cannot add aria-label to the input element unless I change the code.